# Syncing VS Code Workspaces and Folders from PC to Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have sync turned on in VS Code. All of my extensions got sync'd form my PC to my Mac.

I was expecting the Workspaces and folders and .vscode SFTP credentials to migrate as well but they haven't. How can I sync my Workspaces, folders and .vscode credential settings between my machines without manually re-building them? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[VS Code's Settings Sync feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) syncs... settings.

> Settings Sync lets you share your Visual Studio Code configurations such as settings, keybindings, and installed extensions across your machines so you are always working with your favorite setup.

It also syncs user snippets and UI state.

It's doesn't sync workspace folders and their contents. What you're looking for is probably [version control software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) (also called source control management software). For example, [Git](https://git-scm.com/), Mercurial, or Subversion.

As for credentials, if any parts of your credentials are machine-stored, it might be better to have individual machine-stored credential parts for each machine. I would *definitely not* push any machine-stored credentials in any credentials to any cloud-based version control remote such as GitHub.

---

> without manually re-building them

A note on this little statement you made: Even with distributed version control, people usually don't track their output artifacts and / object files in version control- or for that matter, anything that can be *re-generated*. For one thing, it's usually just a waste of space in the version control's history storage. And artifacts can be very machine / platform / architecture dependent.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like I need to rebuild the workspaces, folders and .vscode JSON files manually. Will do...